# Creating unique model for each business

Tags: django

Guys i am new in django this is my first project i am creating accounting app.
 I need this .For example if some one create busines it must have new
 budget expense date   fields.

```
class Business(models.Model):
busines = models.CharField(max_len=60)  

class Add(models.Model):
    budget = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    expense = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: You can link the `Add` objects with a `ForeignKey` to the `Business`, but I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Like every user have his own profile posts etc .can you type the code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i try to explain a bit more about @Willem comment. if you want contact between `Add` instance and `Business` you need have a new field in `Add` model with ForeignKey to related `Business` instance.so :

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business = models.CharField(max_len=60)  

class Add(models.Model):
    budget = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    expense = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField()
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, null=True, blank=True)
```

then every time you want you can create an `Add` instance by this way:

```
new_business_instance = Business.objects.create(business='home_renovations')

new_add_instance = Add.objects.create(budget=100, expense=200, date=some_date, business=new_business_instance)
```

or if you have an `Add` instance from past and now you want add `Business`:

```
some_existence_add.business = instance_of_Business
some_existence_add.save()
```

for more information about ForeignKey you can read [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) from django doc.
and information about making queries through ForeignKey you can read [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/) from django doc too.